# Extend C++ template parameter type names for generated code

Tags: c++, macros, code-formatting

Is it possible to have a C++ template where the template parameter can act as a prefix or suffix for another existing (longer) typename. I am working with code generated from an IDL (Interface Definition), so there are many generated classes with related names. For example, if the IDL defines "Foo" I will have the following list of classes generated. 
`Foo, FooReader, FooWriter, FooSerializer, ...`

I am trying to create a class containing a member variable for each of these generated types... Ideally, I would be able to declare the object with `Wrapper<Foo> obj;`

I can do something like this:

```
#define EXPANDTEMPLATE(type) Wrapper<type, type##Reader, type##Writer, ... >

template <typename T, typename TReader, typename TWriter, ...> class Wrapper {
   T       var1;
   TReader var2;
   TWriter var3;
   ...
};

int main(){
   EXPANDTEMPLATE(Foo) obj;
   //do stuff
}
```

In my case, default constructors won't be an issue so this ***works***, but I would prefer a solution that isn't going to lead the code maintainers to track me down and break my legs.

Is there a better/cleaner solution than creating a template with 15 parameters?

Comment: From reading this question I have no idea what you're trying to *actually do*, aka accomplish.  Questions like: "Is there a better/cleaner solution" ...don't make sense to ask, unless you explain what the *problem* is you're trying to solve.  E.g., working with generated IDL isn't a problem.  Pasting "Reader" on a token in the preprocessor is trivial, and it looks like you know how to do it.  So what are you *doing*?

Comment: (...e.g. in main, `obj` here has members `var1`, `var2`, etc; that have types `DataObject`, `DataObjectReader`, etc; if that's the thing you're trying to do, could the type of obj simply be an unnamed struct, or a `std::tuple`?)

Comment: The objects themselves are going to be made from a fully implemented class which wraps fuctionality from the OpenDDS framework. The _problem_ is I want to avoid typing out boiler plate code for hundreds of data types defined in the IDL, so I want to use a template class. For code readability, I don't want to define a dozen template parameters. Since the template parameters themselves follow a fixed pattern, I was just looking for a streamlined trick to use. It's maybe a boring question, but that's all there is to it.

Comment: I gathered that `FooReader` etc are generated by an IDL tool.  What I'm after is something like (if this is the case) you want to create an object with members of each variant.  Also, could you just edit the question with this clarification?  (It should be part of the question; comments are volatile on s.o.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the OpenDDS documentation, [here](https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/mnb/code-generation-with-opendds-part-i):

> In the file TypeTraits.h we define a templated struct, TypeTraits, to reference the various DDS entities associated with a given data sample structure.
>
> ```
> // TypeTraits.h
> template <typename DDS_STRUCT_T>
> struct TypeTraits
> {
> };
>  
> #define DEFINE_TYPETRAITS(TYPE) \
> template <> \
> struct TypeTraits<TYPE> \
> { \
>     typedef TYPE##TypeSupport TypeSupport; \
>     typedef TYPE##TypeSupportImpl TypeSupportImpl; \
>     typedef TYPE##DataWriter Writer; \
>     typedef TYPE##DataReader Reader; \
> };
> ```
>
> Returning to DDSBase, we can now define CreateWriter() and CreateReader() methods with just one template parameter ...

You could use the same approach in this case.  Given the above macro, you could apply a partial template specialization; in your case, by invoking this macro with `DEFINE_TYPETRAITS(Foo)`.  You may want your own macro to expand to your fifteen variants rather than these specific ones, but given this is in OpenDDS documentation it should be a more familiar approach (in theory) to people who use it.  There may also be other uses for your expanded (or the default if it works) type traits class.

Once you have this specialization (`DEFINE_TYPETRAITS` for your type of interest), you could make a simple template like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    T var1;
    typename TypeTraits<T>::Reader var2;
    typename TypeTraits<T>::Writer var3;
    typename TypeTraits<T>::TypeSupport var4;
    typename TypeTraits<T>::TypeSupportImpl var5;
};
```

...and just do:

```
DEFINE_TYPETRAITS(Foo)
int main()
{
    Wrapper<Foo> obj;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting find. It's looking like I can't do _exactly_ what I was hoping for (i.e. it's just not a feature of C++), but you've revealed another way to sort of hack it together which I can definitely appreciate. I had seen some defined TypeTraits in my generated headers, but I hadn't figured out whether I could leverage it. I'll give it a go tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @Drummerx04 One word of caution, to make this clear... if you write your custom macro, you really want your own custom TypeTraits as well; this is because the existing one "is meant to" be used by the existing macro, and you can't have different forms of the same specialization in your code base.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in my mind is to use [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

The code can look like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Reader;
template <typename T>
class Writer;

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T data;
    Reader<T> reader;
    Writer<T> writer;
};

class Data {};
template<>
class Reader<Data> {};
template<>
class Writer<Data> {};

int main()
{
    Wrapper<Data> wrapper;
    static_cast<void>(wrapper);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite what I need, but I see what you are getting at. In my case, for the "Data" template parameter, I also have a generated class with the name "DataReader" and "DataWriter" which is not a template but a class with a fixed name and definition.